# why seq() function in shinyApps does not work?

Tags: r, shiny, syntax-error, sequence, seq

I tried to create a shinyApp with `seq()` function within the Apps.

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Testing' ,titleWidth = 300)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel"), width = 300)
body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))
uix <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

serverx <- function(input, output, session){

  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
    div(
      sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                  menuItem("Tes 1", tabName = "tes1", icon = icon("dashboard"), selected = TRUE)
                  )
    )
  })

  output$body <- renderUI({
    tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "tes1",
                      fluidRow(column(2, textInput("s1", "From :", value = 1))
                                ,column(2, textInput("s2", "To", value = 7))
                      ),
                      textOutput("result")
             )
    )
    })

  segment_low <- reactiveValues(ba=NULL)
  segment_high <- reactiveValues(ba=NULL)
  results <- reactiveValues(ba=NULL)

  toListen <- reactive({
    list(input$s1, input$s2)
  })

   observeEvent(toListen(),{
    segment_low$ba <- input$s1 %>% as.numeric()
    segment_high$ba <- input$s2 %>% as.numeric()
  })

  observe({
    results$ba <- seq(segment_low$ba,segment_high$ba, 1)
  })

  output$result <- renderText({
    results$ba 
  })

  }

shinyApp(uix, serverx)
```

In that syntax, I would create a variable called `results$ba` because I want to escalate that value in the next time. But it turns out an error :

```
Warning: Error in seq.default: 'from' must be of length 1
  [No stack trace available]
```

Could someone help me how to solve this problem? Since this error just happened if I put the reactiveValues to the `seq()` function, while I input a static input, for example `seq(2,5,1)` it will not return a  error. And I already put the initial `value` for each input in `textInput()` function also.

Kindle need your help, developers!
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're rendering the `s1` and `s2` inputs server-side. Because of this, the server at the beginning renders them as `NULL`, and your `seq` function errors when it gets the `NULL` value.

The simplest thing to do is to add a `req` function to prevent your code from evaluating unless it's getting some non-NULL values.

```
    observe({
        req(segment_low$ba, segment_high$ba)
        results$ba <- seq(segment_low$ba,segment_high$ba, 1)
    })
```

Basically, since you're using observe, which is very eager, you are telling the `seq` function to evaluate right away. By using the `req` function, you're stopping the chain of evaluation from happening unless the segment_low$ba and segment_high$ba have non-NULL values.

Comment: Hi @Sergio thanks for the advice. I've tried and it works well. The explanation is so clear. Well understood :)